# SFML networking Server/Client

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, client-server, sfml

I have just started to learn SFML networking....i am making a server client chatbox...when I run client program on PC it connects to the server which is also running on my PC.....but the problem is that the client program on my laptop does not connect to the server program on my PC....here is the code for server:

```
void main()
{
cout << "Server Running" << endl;
TcpListener listener;
SocketSelector selector;
bool done = false;
vector<TcpSocket*>clients;
listener.getLocalPort();
listener.listen(2000);
selector.add(listener);

while (!done)
{
    if (selector.wait())
    {
        if (selector.isReady(listener))
        {
            TcpSocket *socket = new TcpSocket;

            listener.accept(*socket);
            Packet packet;
            string id;
            string status;
            if (socket->receive(packet) == Socket::Done)
                packet >> id>>status;
            cout << id << " has "<<status;
            clients.push_back(socket);
            selector.add(*socket);
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0;i < clients.size();i++)
            {
                if (selector.isReady(*clients[i]))
                {
                    Packet packet, sendpacket;
                    if (clients[i]->receive(packet) == Socket::Done)
                    {
                        string text;
                        packet >> text;
                        sendpacket << text;
                        for (int j = 0;j < clients.size();j++)
                        {
                            if (i != j)
                            {
                                clients[j]->send(sendpacket);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

for (vector<TcpSocket*>::iterator it = clients.begin();it != clients.end();it++)
    delete *it;
}
```

code for client:

```
#include<SFML/Network.hpp>
#include<SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace sf;
using namespace std;

void main()
{
IpAddress ip = IpAddress::getLocalAddress();
cout << ip << endl;

TcpSocket socket;
bool done = false;

string id;
string status = "connected";
string text = "";

cout << "Enter online id: ";
cin >> id;

socket.connect(ip, 2000);

Packet packet;

packet << id<< status;
socket.send(packet);
socket.setBlocking(false);

RenderWindow window(VideoMode(800, 600, 32), id);
vector<Text> chat;

Font font;
font.loadFromFile("Data/font.ttf");

while (window.isOpen())
{
    Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        switch (event.type)
        {
        case Event::Closed:
            window.close();
            break;
        case Event::KeyPressed:
            if (event.key.code == Keyboard::Escape)
            {
                text.clear();
            }               
            else if (event.key.code == Keyboard::Return)
            {
                Packet packet;
                packet << id + ":" + text;
                socket.send(packet);
                Text displaytext(text, font, 20);
                displaytext.setColor(Color::Green);
                chat.push_back(displaytext);
                text = "";
            }
            break;
        case Event::TextEntered:
            if (event.text.unicode == '\b' && text.size() >0)
            {
                text.erase(text.size() - 1, 1);
            }
            else
            text += event.text.unicode;
            break;
        }
    }

    Packet packet;
    socket.receive(packet);
    string temptext;
    if (packet >> temptext)
    {
        Text displaytext(temptext, font, 20);
        displaytext.setColor(Color::Blue);
        chat.push_back(displaytext);
    }
    int i = 0;
    for (i;i<chat.size();i++)
    {
        chat[i].setPosition(0, i * 20);
        window.draw(chat[i]);
    }

    Text drawtext(text, font, 20);
    drawtext.setColor(Color::Red);
    drawtext.setPosition(0, i * 20);
    window.draw(drawtext);

    window.display();
    window.clear();
}

}
```

I need to know that how my laptop client will find and connect to the server(pc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to get the IP address of your server. Right now, you are feeding the clients IP address to the client, that won't work.

For starters, you could look it up and hard code it, but in the long run, you will need to find a way to make that more dynamic.

And one last thing: there is no such thing as `void main()`. That is undefined behavior, get rid of it. Use a valid entry point, most likely you want to use `int main()`.

Comment: thanks for helping, now i understand what i am doing wrong.......can you please further guide me how i should make client to get to the IP of server(how can i reach out to the server for request)...some code examples can help....